# jQuery :not() selector nesting

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this HTML mark up:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div id="FieldWrap18" class="fieldSettings full" data-dependent="{19}" data-dependson="">
                <input id="Field_0_18" name="Field_0_18" type="checkbox" value="true">
                <input name="Field_0_18" type="hidden" value="false">
                Yes
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="FieldWrap19" class="fieldSettings full" data-dependent="" data-dependson="">
                <input id="Field_0_19" name="Field_0_19" type="checkbox" value="true">
                <input name="Field_0_19" type="hidden" value="false">
                No
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to select the "Yes" field using this selector (I must use the `data-dependent` attribute)

```
$('div:not([data-dependent=""]) input:not([type="hidden"])').on('change', function () {
    alert('Yep!');
});
```

However it is selecting both `input` fields. How do I only select the `non-empty data-dependent non-hidden input`? Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWsP5/) with the non-working code. I know the selector breaks because of the parent `div` that doesn't even have a `data-dependent` attribute, but I don't know how to structure my selector to ignore that div while grabbing the one that has that attribute. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you concerned about _ignoring_ `change` events on hidden inputs? Ordinarily there's nothing that would trigger that event on hidden inputs.

Comment: That's a good point, I think I added that out of desperation trying to figure out a way to get this to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this selector:-

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J3Zts/)

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('div[data-dependent]')
      .not('[data-dependent=""]')
      .find('input:not([type="hidden"])')
      .on('change', function () {
        alert('Yep!');
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do it.

```
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
     var parent = $(this).parent();
     if(parent.data().dependent.length > 0)
         alert('you clicked YES!');
     else
          alert('you clicked NO!');
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chazelton/jWsP5/1/) working.

Comment: As I stated in my description, I must use `data-dependent` as some of my inputs will will not be checkboxes and others wont have that attribute at all...

Comment: yeah I used that. you could have a class that you add to each element that will be the trigger. use that as the selector then when it fires grab the parents data as I showed you and viola you are good to go for checking for null values.